# GNU Make ignoring a phony rule specified by wildcard?

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I am learning some courses about compiling some C code into specific assembly. I decided that the generated assembly should be manually inspected, so I came up with `less something.s` as a "test" rule.

As a fan-but-newbie of Make, I wrote this Makefile:

```
CODES := a

LESS ?= less
CODES_TEST := $(patsubst %,%-test,${CODES})

.PHONY: all test ${CODES_TEST} clean

all: $(patsubst %,%.s,${CODES})

test: all

%-test: %.s
        ${LESS} $^

%.s: %.c
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -S -o $@ $^

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.s
```

And I have this minimal `a.c` file:

```c
int asdfg(void) { return 54321; }
```

I then typed `make a-test` in Bash, expecting `less` showing up with the content of `a.s`, only to be told this:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'a-test'.
```

I got the above response regardless of the presence of `a.s`, which generates normally if I do `make a.s` or just `make` (implicitly runs the first rule, `all`).

I checked my Makefile and I don't think I made a typo or another simple mistake.

1. What did I miss with the above `Makefile`?
2. How can I get Make to execute `less a.s` when I run `make a-test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to be done for `a-test` because the only rule that would make it is the implicit pattern rule:

```
%-test: %.s
        ${LESS} $^
```

and, per the manual [4.6 Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

> The implicit rule search (see Implicit Rules) is skipped for .PHONY targets.

and, since it is `.PHONY`, its mere non-existence does make it out-of-date.

To get around this, while preserving the phoiness, replace:

```
%-test: %.s
        ${LESS} $^
```

with:

```
${CODES_TEST}: %-test: %.s
    ${LESS} $^
```

Then the rule is a static pattern rule and no longer an implicit one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Question 2: How can I get the rule running? (I didn't *add* this question - it's already in my post, at the bottom)

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that you wanted a workaound. Updated.

Comment: What if `${CODES_TEST}` contains 2 or more keywords? (that's why it's plural)

Comment: @iBug There can be any number of targets in a rule, but anyway there is a better idea.

Comment: OK thanks, I got some working `Makefile` that's exactly the same as your latest edit.